Equation in a nilpotent group
Let $G$ be a nilpotent group of class at most $r$
(that is, $\gamma^{r+1}G=1$).
Let elements $g_1,\dotsc,g_n\in G$ be fixed.
We are interested in the set $V\subseteq\mathbb Z^n$ of solutions $x=(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$ of the equation
$$
g_1^{x_1}\dotso g_n^{x_n}=1.
$$
One can prove that $V$ can be given by a system of polynomial equations and congruences
$$
P_i(x)=0,
$$
$$
Q_j(x)\equiv0\pmod{m_j},
$$
where
$m_j$ are positive integers and
$P_i$ and $Q_j$ are integer polynomials
of degree at most $r$.
The proof relies on counting degrees of the multiplication and exponentiation polynomials (which express the group operations of a free nilpotent group in the Mal'cev coordinates) and their compositions.
Where can I find this fact in the literature?

To be pedantic, the normal meaning of "nilpotent group $G$ of class $r$" is $\gamma^{r+1}G= 1$ and $\gamma^rG \ne 1$.

Yes, for this reason I prefer the wording "$r$-step nilpotent" (which I use for: nilpotent of class $\le r$).

I replaced the words "class $r$" by "class at most $r$".

I wrote the proof, see Part II, especially Theorem 9.1, of my preprint "Homotopy similarity of maps. Maps of the circle" http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~ssp/sim-1.pdf .

I guess you should have a look at « Knapsack problem in groups » (where we usually take $x_i$ non-negative integers). It has been studied in nilpotent groups, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05145 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08584 , but I don’t think the specific result you’re asking for was written down beforehand.
